Should executing PACE authentication twice cause errors?
I am using JMRTD library for reading data from eID and PassportService doPace() method works fine. But when I do another doPace(), immediately after, I get: 
PICC side error in static PACE key derivation step (SW = 0x6986: COMMAND NOT ALLOWED)

Reason I consider this to be a problem is not because I need to do this twice in a program, but that it throws this same error when I run program twice. Even if I disconnect card reader and reconnect, same error.
If I wait a minute this issue is resolved. I am not sure but there must be some persistent timeout on the card causing this.
Any idea on how to solve this?

0x6986 commonly happens when there is no proper select command of which applet to run on the Javacard. I don't know JMRTD so no idea how helpful this comment is but potentially running doPace() twice doesn't trigger a select applet between the calls?

@Asthor There is a SELECT_MF at the start of a program. So running the program second time does select MF and throws this error on first doPace after it. So I assume the selection is not a problem, unless selecting mf is not the same as selecting an applet? (Im somewhat newbie)

It is perfectly legal to complain about two attempts to perform PACE in the same session, see TR-3110, part 2 (I have version 2.21 from December 2016), section 3.2.2

The eIDAS token MUST NOT accept more than one execution of PACE within one session.

Unfortunately the 69 86 status is not covered by TR-3110, Part 3, section B.14.2. "General Authenticate", which means it has to be considered as "operating system dependent error", so taking MRTDs from another hardware supplier may help.
My current assumption is, that your reader is the cause for the scheme to work again after one minute by powering down the card after disconnect. You may try to check its documentation for a possibility to modify this.

Same thing happens when I remove the card from reader, so it's not a power problem. Do cards have persistent storage? How do I reset the session? I'll look at the library source code but close() and open() methods are not fixing this. Neither is hot reset (SELECT-MF apdu)
